# How can I put a hash into a sqlite3 database?

Tags: ruby

I've got several hashes stored in an array in memory, like:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :020 > grok.tracks[0]
=> {:track_id=>1391, :name=>"Becoming a Better Developer", :artist=>"Ruby Rogues", :album=>"Ruby Rogues", :genre=>"Podcast", :kind=>"MPEG audio file", :size=>110164706, :total_time=>4596271, :year=>2011, :date_modified=>"2011-08-29T04:49:04", :date_added=>"2011-08-29T04:49:04", :bit_rate=>192, :sample_rate=>44100, :release_date=>"2011-08-25T17:25:43", :persistent_id=>"6E564B7750B54D85", :track_type=>"File", :podcast=>true, :unplayed=>true, :location=>"file://localhost/Users/lunks/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Podcasts/Ruby%20Rogues/Becoming%20a%20Better%20Developer.mp3", :file_folder_count=>4, :library_folder_count=>1} 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :021 > grok.tracks.size
=> 14152
```

And I want to save them on an SQLite3 database. My database already has the table and all the columns I need. The database is named `Library.sqlite3` and the table is `tracks`. 
How can I put all the hashes in the Sqlite3 database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlite",
  :database  => "path/to/Library.sqlite3"
)

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# read hashes from wherever you have them
# grok = Grok.read_tracks

for track_hash in grok.tracks
  track = Track.new(track_hash)
  track.save
end
```